# Only Accept Limted Images in Input File Field (Example 5 Images)

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have a input File upload field in my HTMl, i want to get only 5 images, selecting more than 5 image should display warning or alert anything.
How to achieve this with javascript or jquery?

Answer (score 0):

You could try something like the following.

```
$("input[type='file']").change(function() {
  var $fileUpload = $("input[type='file']");
  if ($fileUpload.get(0).files.length > 5) {
    alert("You can only upload a maximum of 5 files");
    $(this).val("")
  }
});
```

**Demo**

```js
$("input[type='file']").change(function() {
  var $fileUpload = $("input[type='file']");
  if ($fileUpload.get(0).files.length > 5) {
    alert("You can only upload a maximum of 5 files");
    $(this).val("")
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="file" multiple />
```

Comment: I think, we don't actually need to parse the length in integer..! As it will always return an integer value..!

Comment: @RohitSharma True, bit tired, thanks for pointing it out.

Answer (score 0):

You can check the size of the input, and clear the files if there are too many:

```js
const fileUploadLimit = 2;

const resetFileInput = input => {
    input.type = '';
    input.type = 'file';
}

document.querySelector('input').onchange = (e) => {
  const { files } = e.target;
  if (files.length > fileUploadLimit) {
    console.log(`cannot upload more than ${fileUploadLimit} files`);
    resetFileInput(e.target);
  }
}
```

```html
<input type="file" name="img" multiple>
```